# How to split array of object by specific object field in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

This code is ugly, how to do better?

```
todos = Todo.all

@todos_1 = Array.new
@todos_2 = Array.new
@todos_3 = Array.new

todos.each do |doc|   
  if doc.category == nil 
    @ntodos_1 << doc 
  end
  if doc.category == "something" 
    @todos_2 << doc 
  end
  if doc.frame == "whatever" 
    @todos_3 << doc 
  end
```

Comment: What should happen if `doc.frame == 'whatever' && doc.category == 'something'`? Can you please provide a proper specification of what the code should be doing, preferably including test cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementing the existing answer, let's assume you are working with "normal" Ruby objects, not a ORM:

```
todos_by_category = todos.group_by(&:category)
```

To be used:

```
>> todos_by_category["some_category"]
#=> [todo1, todo2, ...]
```

Comment: The scope solution mentioned above is handy. I was exploring Ruby and your answer is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Todo.group("category").order("category")` to organize the result set and then loop over it, knowing that when category changes you are at the next grouping.

Alternatively, it might be useful to create scopes for the Todo model:

```rb
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :something, where(:category => "something")
  scope :whatever, where(:category => "whatever")
end
```

This would allow you to assign the results to instance variables instead of iterating over all results within your controller:

```rb
@something = Todo.something
@whatever = Todo.whatever
```

Comment: That is nice! However it would send two db requests in that case. What if I would want to send just one db request and do the splitting in ruby?

Comment: The first part of the answer would give you a solution for that. Basically, you need to keep a reference to the previous iteration to compare against. When they don't match, you're at the next category.

Answer (score 0):

At least the first two if's could be combined in one case:

```
todos.each do |doc|   
  case doc.category 
    when nil 
      @ntodos_1 << doc 
    when "something" 
      @todos_2 << doc 
  end
  if doc.frame == "whatever" 
    @todos_3 << doc 
  end
```

You also know elsif?
    }